# C# remotely connect to an Oracle database with DbProviderFactory,ORA-03135: connection lost contact

Tags: c#, oracle

C# remotely connects to an Oracle database with `DbProviderFactory`, but after a period of time, I get this error:

> ORA-03135: connection lost contact

The query code looks like this:

```
public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string sql, IList<DbParameter> parameters, CommandType commandType)
{
    using (DbCommand command = CreateDbCommand(sql, parameters, commandType))
    {
        try
        {
            using (DbDataAdapter adapter = providerFactory.CreateDataAdapter())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(data);
                return data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (command.Connection != null)
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                    command.Connection.Dispose();//①
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
}

private DbCommand CreateDbCommand(string sql, IList<DbParameter> parameters, CommandType commandType)
{
    DbConnection connection = providerFactory.CreateConnection();
    DbCommand command = providerFactory.CreateCommand();
    connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    command.CommandText = sql;
    command.CommandType = commandType;
    command.Connection = connection;

    if (!(parameters == null || parameters.Count == 0))
    {
        foreach (DbParameter parameter in parameters)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
    }
    return command;
}
```

If the program is connected Oracle for a long time, then Oracle closes the connection because of a time out. If I don't use `Connection.Dispose ();`, `DbProviderFactory` will always cache the connection to Oracle and cause the program to be unable to connect to the database, so it uses `Connection.Dispose();` to release the connection to Oracle.

At least once after an `ORA-03135` exception is reported, the function can be executed again. And the normal query can be made, but for a period of time, there will be throw an exception of ORA-03135  again.

What can I do to solve this problem thoroughly?

I've come up with a way to catch and judge the 0RA-03135 exception at the time when the function produces the exception. If it's 0RA-03135 exception, I'll execute the function again. But the method doesn't seem to be the real solution. Do you have a better solution?